# How do I communicate from VB6 to a server-side PHP API?

Tags: php, http, vb6

This is a question about communication between VB6 and server-side PHP.

WooCommerce has a plugin that lets you serialize sales of software products. It communications to software applications via a PHP API. The syntax of an API call is like this:

```
wp_get_request('http://174.120.19.162/~fab/?wc_api=software_api&request=request_key&Secret_Key=<sekret>&email=<email>')
```

I have a VB6 application that needs to communicate with this api. I am using the following code to send the URL request:

```
blah = INetObject.OpenURL("http://174.120.19.162/~fab/wp_get_request('http://174.120.19.162/~fab/?wc_api=software_api&request=request_key&Secret_Key=<sekret>&email=<email>')")
```

The API is supposed to return a JSON object (blah) which I then parse to get the data I want. However it is not working. I've tried various syntactical permutations to no avail. Mostly I get an XML description of the destination page, so my question is this:

How do I communicate to this API from VB6? I've been working this issue for about a week with no results.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. The "Secret Key" is just for the test order. Secret Keys are changed for every order so I'm not giving anything away. When I tried your suggestion I got the following:

Comment: Here's part of what is returned:  <!DOCTYPE html>  <html lang= "en-US" prefix= "og:htttp://ogp.me/.ns#>  <head>  <meta charset = "UTF-8"/>  and much more. It appears to describe the page of the URL in the call. The WooCommerce API doesn't appear to be triggered by the "wp_get_request" text. According to the WooCommerce docs, the API is supposed to be listening all the time.  Because I'm getting some response, I think the call is getting made from VB6.  I have no clue about web site stuff so there may be something obvious I'm missing.

Comment: Exactly right, Deanna. You've saved me many hours. I'd give you 5 stars, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the API to be used internally in wordPress code, and what you need to call externally.

This sample was given by you and calls a function internal to WordPress to make the HTTP request:

```
wp_get_request('http://174.120.19.162/~fab/?wc_api=software_api&request=request_key&Secret_Key=<sekret>&email=<email>')
```

The equivalant of the `wp_get_request()` in VB6 would be `INetObject.OpenURL()`:

```
blah = INetObject.OpenURL('http://174.120.19.162/~fab/?wc_api=software_api&request=request_key&Secret_Key=<sekret>&email=<email>')
```

Your mistake was trying to mash the two together, thinking `wp_get_request` was part of the HTTP API itself.

Comment: @user1422047 If this did help, please [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking the green tick to the left of the post.