# VB6 to read PHP file on website for authentication process

Tags: php, vb6

I want to make a VB6 form read a PHP file on a website which contains a string which is a password, it save the password into a string and compare the entry the user inserts with the string to allow accessing (maybe I use encrypting and decoding methods).

I don't have any problem with the above except how to read a PHP file on a website to fetch the string I want. The PHP file will be made by the website's webmaster and he will send me the text of the file to use it with my software. But I really don't know how to read a PHP file - is it like HTML a web browser can read it? or by scripting?

The PHP will contains the password which can be change by the administrator of the website as a string. The user of my software have to be a member on the website and asks the administrator for the password then he/she will be certificated to use the software. In the event of load the form has to read that PHP file and fetch the password and save it in a string datatype.

Then compare it with the password the user inserts into a textbox on form. Once they are the same. The form unload and show another form which is the main form. If password is wrong, msgbox incorrect password. I don't know how to read a PHP file on a website. I have an approval from the administrator of the website to do that as the software is related to the material of the website.

Comment: Would you explain more about what end result you want? Do you want the VB6 form to log into the PHP website?

Comment: I edited question and added a clarification about what I need.

Comment: What would stop me, as an unauthorised user, visiting that URL and retrieving the password via my browser?

Comment: It will be encrypted and the software will decode it ..

Comment: In what manner will it be encrypted, exactly?

Comment: A possible duplicate, if you decide to use XML: [http get in vb6 and receive xml data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11606843/http-get-in-vb6-and-receive-xml-data), or more generally: [How do I communicate from VB6 to a server-side PHP API?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15126200/how-do-i-communicate-from-vb6-to-a-server-side-php-api/15243439#15243439)

Comment: A better way to do this would be to send the authentication details to the server which then returns a good or bad response. This stops anyone being able to request the password which they're free to decrypt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that you won't "read the PHP file" at all.  Usually servers are configured so that a GET that hits a "PHP file" causes the script to be interpreted, and the script creates and sends a response.

Nothing prevents such a PHP page from sending back plain text in whatever encoding you want, or it could send back XML or HTML... or almost anything else.

The easiest ways to do this in VB6 are to either:

- Use the built-in AsyncRead method of a simple hidden UserControl you'd write (just a few lines of code), or else
- Use the MSXML 3.0 XmlHttpRequest (MSXML2.XMLHTTP) object which should be present in Windows even as far back as Win95 if IE 5.x was ever installed.

In all supported versions of Windows (Vista and later) you should also have the WinHttpRequest object available as part of the OS with nothing to install or deploy.  This may offer the advantage of not using the UrlMon/IE cache at all, thus saving you from a common headache with XmlHttpRequest.

I'd pass on the crusty old WinInet control that shipped with VB6 though.